# Why do functions from my Rails plugin not work without specifically requiring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need some help with my plugin. I want to extend `ActiveRecord::Base` with a method that initializes another method that can be called in the controller.

It will look like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    robot_catch :title, :text
    ...
end
```

My attempt at extending the `ActiveRecord::Base` class with `robot_catch` method looks like following. The function will initialize the specified attributes (in this case `:title` and `:text`) in a variable and use `class_eval` to make the `robot?` function available for the user to call it in the controller:

```
module Plugin
    module Base
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        module ClassMethods
            def robot_catch(*attr)
                @@robot_params = attr

                self.class_eval do
                    def robot?(params_hash)
                        # Input is the params hash, and this function
                        # will check if the some hashed attributes in this hash
                        # correspond to the attribute values as expected,
                        # and return true or false.
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, Plugin::Base
```

So, in the controller, this could be done:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def create
        @article = Article.new(params[:article])

        if @article.robot? params
            # Do not save this in database, but render
            # the page as if it would have succeeded
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

My question is whether if I am right that `robot_catch` is class method. This function is to be called inside a model, as shown above. I wonder if I am extending the `ActiveRecord::Base` the right way. The `robot?` function is an instance method without any doubt.

I am using Rails 3.2.22 and I installed this plugin as a gem in another project where I want to use this functionality.

Right now, it only works if I specifically `require` the gem in the model. However, I want it the functionality to be included as a part of `ActiveRecord::Base` without requiring it, otherwise I'd have to `require` it in every model I want to use it, not particularly *DRY*. Shouldn't the gem be automatically loaded into the project on Rails start-up?

**EDIT:** Maybe callbacks (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html) would be a solution to this problem, but I do not know how to use it. It seems a bit obscure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

I found out the solution myself. Bundler will not autoload dependencies from a gemspec that my project uses, so I had to require all third party gems in an engine.rb file in the lib/ directory of my app in order to load the gems. Now everything is working as it should.

Second: the `robot_catch` method is a class method.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest you make sure that [none of the many many built in Rails validators meet your needs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Then if that's the case, what you actually want is a custom validator.

Building a custom validator is not as simple as it might seem, the basic class you'll build will have this structure:

```
class SpecialValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # Fill this with your validation logic
    # Add to record.errors if validation fails
  end
end
```

Then in your model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :text, special: true 
end
```

I would **strongly** suggest making sure what you want is not already built, chances are it is. Then use [resources like this](http://www.perfectline.co/blog/2010/04/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators/) or [ruby guides resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) to continue going down the custom validator route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the as the function is actually not a validator, it does unfortunately not answer my question. I am sorry for the misunderstanding! I thought I would just give this example so that it sketches the actual problem in a simplified way.

Comment: It could be helpful for you to include the actual intended behaviour you want this code to result in. Maybe with that, it will become more clear to what you want this code for?

Comment: I can unfortunately not present the actual problem, as I am restricted to a contract. But the problem sketched here is near the reality.

Comment: I made it more specific towards my project now :-)

Comment: I see. I still think the validator is the closest thing to what you want. Otherwise maybe a simpler module would do? One with a class and instance method that you include for your AR models. Either way it looks like a very specific problem, I hope you find a suitable answer.

Comment: It might be quite close, but I don't want it to be colliding with the validator methods that are run upon save or others, since the action taken after finding out that the form input originates a bot is different.
Your next suggestion is interesting, but I think the `robot?` instance method should not be callable when it the `robot_catch` is not called. I could make an exception error for that in `robot?`, but thought this solution was prettier.